# storing as smallint, querying as int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, optimization, computed-column

A multi-billion-row fact table in our database has 10 measures stored as `int` columns. The value ranges for some of these columns won't ever be above the +/-32K range of a `smallint`. To save I/O, we're investigating whether it's practical to store these columns as `smallint` instead of `int`.

But we're concerned about what problems might crop up from doing this, including:

- `SUM(SomeSmallInt)` will frequently overflow, so many queries would have to be rewritten to cast these smallints to ints before aggregating, e.g. `SUM(CAST(SomeSmallInt as int))`.
- This table is read in many places, so changing the data type of these columns might involve a lot of review, change, and testing.

So we're wondering if there's a lower-cost solution that would store as smallint but expose the colunms as ints to readers. Like this:

- create smallint "storage" columns that the table's (only) writer will use, but otherwise no other client will care about.
- to support existing readers, create int-typed computed columns that are the same names as the original int columns.

What are the pros and cons of this approach? What can go wrong?  Is there a better way to reduce storage & I/O without causing problems with overflow and requiring existing readers to be rewritten?

Comment: Data compression should do exactly what you're suggesting - an int that fits in smallint will be stored as such, and then you get further benefits from dictionary...

Comment: I will second @AaronBertrand 's suggestion, provided you are on Enterprise Edition :).

Comment: Also, data compression will benefit the buffer space needed since compressed pages are stored in memory in a compressed state.  Clearly, the indicator here is to ensure you are not already CPU-bound.

Comment: In my opinion you are already doing the best thing, Store the data as a SMALLINT and when you need to aggregate it you can use the CAST inside the aggregate command (Casting up is a very quick command / much quicker then decompressing the data). Compressing the data will slow comparisons and other read write tasks so unless you really need the space i do not recommend this.  Bottom line is, whats more important Speed or Disk space.

Comment: I think CREATE VIEW would do what you're specifically asking for. Data compression would likely be a better option than changing data types though.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the benefit of data compression for this question, I quickly built the following test:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.IntTest
(
    IntTest_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_IntTest
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SmallIntTest
(
    SmallIntTest_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_SmallIntTest
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.IntTest (IntTest_ID)
SELECT TOP(65535) 
    CONVERT(SMALLINT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id, o2.object_id) - 32768)
FROM sys.objects o
    , sys.objects o1
    , sys.objects o2
ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id, o2.object_id;

INSERT INTO dbo.SmallIntTest (SmallIntTest_ID)
SELECT TOP(65535) 
    CONVERT(SMALLINT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id, o2.object_id) - 32768)
FROM sys.objects o
    , sys.objects o1
    , sys.objects o2
ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id, o2.object_id;


SELECT o.name
    , i.name
    , p.partition_number
    , p.rows
    , au.used_pages
    , au.total_pages
    , AvgRowsPerPage = p.rows / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), au.used_pages) 
FROM sys.allocation_units au WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOLOCK) ON ((au.type = 1 OR au.type = 3) AND au.container_id = p.hobt_id) OR (au.type = 2 AND au.container_id = p.partition_id)
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON p.object_id = i.object_id AND p.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo'
    AND o.name IN (
        'IntTest'
        , 'SmallIntTest'
    );
```

The output from the last query, showing actual pages used by each table, is:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|      NAME       | PARTITION | ROWS  | USED_PAGES | TOTAL_PAGES | AVG ROWS    |
|                 | NUMBER    |       |            |             | PER PAGE    |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| PK_IntTest      | 1         | 65535 | 92         | 97          | 712.3369573 |
| PK_SmallIntTest | 1         | 65535 | 92         | 97          | 712.3369573 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

As you can see from the above results, compressed INTs containing SMALLINTs actually consume precisely the same amount of space.